# Finding resource utilization on a web site

Tags: java

I am doing a project to find CPU, memory and IO utilization consumed by a page to get loaded after logging into it.can any one help me?

Comment: Which part of your project is giving you a problem?  Please give us more details, including server brand , OS flavour and version, etc.

Comment: I am trying this to be done in java platform.Any API's or third party tools wil help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear as you haven't mentioned the technology, hmm..nonetheless:

- If you are using javascript, then you
  can profile using [Javascript Runtime
  Profiler](http://www.mozilla.org/performance/jsprofiler.html) and others.
- If you are using java then you can
  use [OPtimize IT/Jprofiler](http://www.codework.com/jprofiler/order.html) and
  others

Ofcourse, this is not the exlusive list, but until you give concrete details, this ist :)

Comment: Thank u suraj,i have edited my question for better understanding,cud u help me out,I am a fresher.

Comment: @Arvind...what technology does the project use?

Answer (score 0):

[HP GlancePlus software](http://www.openview.hp.com/products/gplus/index.html) is a system performance monitoring tool that provides numerous views into a system's performance. It tracks CPU, memory, disk, and network resources. You can view all the metrics in customizable graphical displays and set up alarms for application response measurement. You can drill into a single process for CPU, memory utilization, and even system call metrics. With GlancePlus you can easily examine system activities using rule-based metrics. This allows you to tailor system performance rules and characterize each computer in the system to identify and resolve performance bottlenecks.